# isup.me reported site down but I still can access website like normal

Tags: nginx, web-server, varnish, cloudflare

I have nginx as backend running WordPress (with w3tc cache plugin installed), varnish as reserve caching proxy, and cloudflare set up.

Sometimes, I see `isup.me` reported my website is down but in fact it's still up. i can still login server and everything is running fine. the website is still accessible.

Can anyone shred some light into this for me?

UPDATE:
- restarting varnish fixes it (I guess). I did it twice and both time isup.me is reporting the site is back after a few minutes. Probably varnish related issue?

Comment: Maybe isup.me is down?

Comment: I thought about it at first but i checked other website of mine and it's still working.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment yet so can only provide an answer.

Try a service like pingdom. That will check from a number of locations and is probably more reliable then a service like isup.me

The benefit of using two services, is that you can see if it's a problem on their end or yours.

You may want to check your server logs (web server access logs) to see if you can see requests from isup.me, or maybe they're being blocked by your firewall.

If you're able to provide more information you may get more helpful advice.

Comment: Please let me know if this answers you question (if so it would be great if you marked it as the correct answer). If you feel your question is still not answered let me know how I can help!